# Jsoup + ссылочный парсинг

Tags: jsoup, html, java, парсер

Подскажите, как ходить по ссылкам и парсить страницы с помощью Jsoup-а?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну как у авторов написано
http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links

или, Вам, что-то конкретное не понятно?...уж больно вопрос размытый)

Comment: Ок, похоже это то, что мне нужно. Спасибо.

Comment: аре ю вэлкам)

Answer (score 1):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get(); 
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
```

http://jsoup.org/